# Managing PHP processes on Windows 7 (with WAMP)

Tags: windows-7, windows, wamp

Is there a way to manage (especially list and kill) long-running PHP processes on a Windows 7 system set up with WAMP?

Every once in a while, I'll accidentally throw an infinite loop into a PHP process and want to kill it.  Right now, all I can think to do is to restart all my WAMP services but sometimes the PHP processes manage to survive right through the restart, i.e., I still see them outputting to logs even after WAMP's restarted.  And if the process isn't logging, then I have no way at all to know when/if it's been killed.  Not to mention, this will wipe out everything I'm doing with WAMP, not just a single process.

I don't seem to see anything relevant in the Windows Task Manager, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is looping, you should certainly be able to see it doing so in task manager.

However, I'd recommend switching from Task Manager to [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) so that you get much more detail and control. You might also need to run it as Admin depending on how you have WAMP set up & don't forget to "show all user" tasks not just your own.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter in the php.ini file that controls how long a web page using PHP is allowed to run before it is automatically terminated.

So as long as you are not talking about using PHP CLI ( Command Line Interface ) then you can set this to a sensible value and then just wait for your infinite loop to get kicked out.

Look for

```
max_execution_time = 60
```

Set it to some sensible value, normally between 30 and 60 seconds. If its set to zero that means Never Timeout.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also have long-running processes that are well-behaved and that I don't want to get killed.

Comment: Well as PHP runs as a module of Apache the only way to kill the long running PHP script is to kill Apache.